# Why my Raycast2D works from time to time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to destroy note by pressing the button, but rays destroy the half of them.
Here's the video for the context: https://youtu.be/cRpxwBUZApk

I've expected that objects will destroy normaly, but it happens time-to-time.
Object that I'm trying to destroy is not trigger and have it's own layermask that I've set on the destructor script.

I've tried to make rays always cast out of objects with Update(), but it didn't work.

Here's the code:

```
//RaycastHit2D hit;
public LayerMask layerMask;
[SerializeField] private InputActionReference actionRef;
private InputAction test;
[HideInInspector] public Vector2 direction;
Animator anim;
GameObject note;
bool isPress;

void Start()
{
    actionRef.action.performed += context => {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, direction, 1.25f, layerMask);
        if(hit.collider != null){
            DestroyImmediate(hit.collider.gameObject);
            SongManager.instance.Score += 100;
            SongManager.instance.Combo += 1;
        }
        anim.SetInteger("AnimState", 1);
    };

    actionRef.action.canceled += context => {
        anim.SetInteger("AnimState", 0);
    };

    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void Update(){
    //if(hit.collider != null){
        //note = hit.collider.gameObject;
    //}
}
```

Here's the object code:

```
[HideInInspector] public bool is7K;
[HideInInspector] public SpriteRenderer sr;
[HideInInspector] public Vector2 StartPos, EndPos;
[HideInInspector] public float SetBeat, RealBeat, SongBeatPos;

void Start(){
    if(is7K){
        transform.localScale = new Vector2(0.75f, 0.75f);
    }
}

void Update()
{
    SongBeatPos = SongManager.instance.songPositionInBeats;
    float PosSet = (SongBeatPos - RealBeat) / (SetBeat - RealBeat); // (обновляемое время - время от спавна = таймер) / (настроенное время - время от спавна = задержка)
    transform.position = Vector2.LerpUnclamped(StartPos, EndPos, PosSet);

    if(PosSet > 1.25f){
        DestroyImmediate(gameObject);
        SongManager.instance.Score -= 50;
        SongManager.instance.Combo = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The raycast Code is in `Start`, it will only run once and never hit anything again after. Also it is recommended to use `Destroy` rather than `DestroyImmediate`. Plus: Raycasts are physics stuff, so I recommend doing that in FixedUpdate.

Comment: In start code Raycast sets to new unity input system. when i press the button, it activates an action. when action activated, it goes through the instructions that i've set in script. so it works when i press the button but not always. but thanks for saying about fixedUpdate, i will try it tomorrow

Comment: Ah, right, you subscribe to the event using `+=` - didn't see that.